# Python: Finding the Number of Items in Combinations of Categories

Tags: python, xml

Using Python, reading data from an xml file, I am trying to find how many items exist in different combinations of "usage" cagegories.

```xml
  <type name="LugWrench">
    <nominal>30</nominal>
    <category name="tools" />
    <usage name="Industrial" />
  </type>
  <type name="Lunchmeat">
    <nominal>20</nominal>
    <category name="food" />
    <tag name="shelves" />
    <usage name="Town" />
    <usage name="Office" />
    <usage name="School" />
    <value name="Tier2" />
    <value name="Tier3" />
  </type>
  <type name="NylonKnifeSheath">
    <nominal>20</nominal>
    <category name="tools" />
    <usage name="Hunting" />
    <usage name="Coast" />
  </type>
```

What I'd like Python to do is go through the XML, extract all the usage names and generate all the different combinations of possibilities, but it's not the XML I am having trouble with, it's the Python.

Some usage categories, may not be in the same order. They might be `[office, school, town]` instead of `[town, office school]`. They might contain other words, too, like military, police, village, etc. I can get Python to build me a list of all the possible usage names, but I can't figure out how to build a list of all the combinations of usage names.

Each would be and example of a list or a list within a list:

```
[Hunting, Coast]
[Coast, Hunting, Village]
[Industrial, Farm]
[Village, Farm, Town, Hunting]
```

This gets the usage categories, but I don't know how to put them in a unique list and ensure they aren't duplicated.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
types = ET.parse('types.xml')
rootTypes = types.getroot()
useList = []
for itemTypes in types.findall('./type'):
    for usage in itemTypes.findall("usage"):
        use = (usage.get("name"))
            if use in useList:
                continue
            else:
                useList.append(usage.get("name"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using python set() will help you. You can cast your list to a set() and it will remove the unique elements in that list.

```
possible_usage_combinations = [] # List of sets, it will hold all possible usage combinations
for itemTypes in types.findall('./type'):
    useList = [] # Reset useList
    for usage in itemTypes.findall("usage"):
        use = (usage.get("name"))
        if use in useList:
            continue
        else:
            useList.append(usage.get("name"))
    if set(useList) not in possible_usage_combinations:
        possible_usage_combinations.append(set(useList))
    else:
        # useList already exist in possible_usage_combinations
        continue

print(possible_usage_combinations) # [{"Industrial"}, {"tools", "Hunting", "Coast"}, ... <and so on>]

if set(["Hunting", "tools", "Coast"]) in possible_usage_combinations:
    print("True") # set(["Hunting", "tools", "Coast"]) is the same as {"tools", "Hunting", "Coast"}, so this will print "True"
```

I hope this help or points you to the correct direction.

Comment: Works perfectly except that it also creates a set called `'set()',`

Answer (score 1):

You can append the new combination of sorted list only, because the xml tags must not have the same order. I assum the order is not important for you.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from io import StringIO

xml="""<root><type name="LugWrench">
    <nominal>30</nominal>
    <category name="tools" />
    <usage name="Industrial" />
  </type>
  <type name="Lunchmeat">
    <nominal>20</nominal>
    <category name="food" />
    <tag name="shelves" />
    <usage name="Town" />
    <usage name="Office" />
    <usage name="School" />
    <value name="Tier2" />
    <value name="Tier3" />
  </type>
  <type name="NylonKnifeSheath">
    <nominal>20</nominal>
    <category name="tools" />
    <usage name="Hunting" />
    <usage name="Coast" />
  </type>
  <type name="SatMan">
    <nominal>20</nominal>
    <category name="tools" />
    <usage name="coast" />
    <usage name="hunting" />
  </type></root>"""

file=StringIO(xml)

tree = ET.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()

names = []
usages = []
types = root.findall('.//type')

use = []
for name in types:
    names.append(name.get('name'))
    for usage in name:
        if usage.tag == 'usage':
            use_name = usage.get('name')
            # make it casesensitive if cost should be count equal as Coast
            use.append(use_name.upper())
    use.sort()
    if use not in usages:
        usages.append(use)
    use =[]

# List of combination lists
print('Number of branches at all', len(types))
print('Number of combinations', len(usages))
print("Unique combination lists:", usages)

# or if you will see only the category list and not the combinations
name_attrib=[]
for l in usages:
    for name in l:
        if name not in name_attrib:
            name_attrib.append(name)
            
print("Uniqueexisting names:", name_attrib)
```

Output:

```
Number of branches at all 4
Number of combinations 3
Unique combination lists: [['INDUSTRIAL'], ['OFFICE', 'SCHOOL', 'TOWN'], ['COAST', 'HUNTING']]
Unique existing names: ['INDUSTRIAL', 'OFFICE', 'SCHOOL', 'TOWN', 'COAST', 'HUNTING']
```

You can use `use.append(use_name.lower()` method, if you will be sure that e.g. Hunting and hunting should be managed as equal.

Answer (score 0):

> This gets the usage categories, but I don't know how to put them in a unique list and ensure they aren't duplicated.

Below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<r>  <type name="LugWrench">
    <nominal>30</nominal>
    <category name="tools" />
    <usage name="Industrial" />
  </type>
  <type name="Lunchmeat">
    <nominal>20</nominal>
    <category name="food" />
    <tag name="shelves" />
    <usage name="Town" />
    <usage name="Office" />
    <usage name="School" />
    <value name="Tier2" />
    <value name="Tier3" />
  </type>
  <type name="NylonKnifeSheath">
    <nominal>20</nominal>
    <category name="tools" />
    <usage name="Hunting" />
    <usage name="Coast" />
  </type></r>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
usage_set = set(u.attrib['name'] for u in root.findall('.//usage'))
print('Unique usage below:')
print(usage_set)
```

Unique usage below:

```
{'Industrial', 'Office', 'School', 'Town', 'Coast', 'Hunting'}
```